# Make shiny's `dateRangeInput`'s `end` always bigger than `start`

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm making a shiny app with `dateRangeInput`. I want to make the date selection in such a way, that the user cannot select smaller date in second date input than first date input.
[image: example image]
For example from the above image, `shiny` now let's user select dates from 2017 in second date input after having selected July 26,2018 in first date input. I now want to make changes such that second date input always starts a day after first date input, like user can't select or even see July 26,2018 in second input and always sees a day after that like July 27,2018, after selecting July 26,2018 in first date input. I've check documentation for `dateRangeInput`, nothing such was available there.
So, how do i do this?

Comment: I've made the question more informative with an example. check it now.

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2043) related GitHub issue.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to prevent user from selecting start > end can be found in shinyWidgets:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::airDatepickerInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                                   range = TRUE,
                                   value = c("2010-01-01", "2001-12-31")),
  verbatimTextOutput("res")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    paste("Start at", input$daterange[1], "and end at", input$daterange[2])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```